# How to search in cassandra case-insensitive?

Tags: python, django, cassandra, cqlengine

I am learning `cassandra` with `Python` and specially with `Django 2` using `cqlengine`. I am trying to search in database where I search for string that starts with the search parameter but I want to make it case insensitive. So if I have following data

```
-------------------------------
|    PKID    |     String     |
-------------------------------
|    1234    |     FOObar     |
|    4321    |     FoOBar     |
|    5665    |     IreALLy    |
|    5995    |     DontknoW   |
|    8765    |     WHatTOdo   |
|    4327    |     foobaR     |
-------------------------------
```

So if I want to search for string that starts with `foo`, I should get all three records. I searched for the solution and I found one comment on stackoverflow that everything is byte in cassandra and so it is not possible but I also found something that says I need to write custom function to do it.

For Django I am using [django-cassandra-engine](https://github.com/r4fek/django-cassandra-engine) to create model. It is an implementation of cqlengine for django. So when I create my model, is there anything that I need to add in it? My test model is

```
class TestModel(DjangoCassandraModel):
    key_id = columns.UUID(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    string = columns.Text()
```

I looked for it in cqlengine docs but couldn't find anything helpful. So I am seeking for help here on stackoverflow.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can use so-called [SASI-index (SSTable Attached Secondary Index)](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/cql/cql/cql_using/useSASIIndex.html) to do it in Cassandra itself (although it's marked as experimental feature). You can define indexes for doing prefix, range, or substring search, and when configuring index, you can specify that you want case-insensitive strings:

```
CREATE CUSTOM INDEX index_name ON table (field) 
  USING 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.SASIIndex'
  WITH OPTIONS = { 
    'mode': 'PREFIX', // if you want to search only for 'starting with'
    'case_sensitive': 'false'
};
```

Although I'm not sure, will cqlengine pickup this functionality out of the box, or not.

Here is [very detailed blog post](http://www.doanduyhai.com/blog/?p=2058) about SASI-indexes.

Comment: Thanks @Alex. I will read the blog post and try to implement it in my database and see if I can get it working.

Comment: Im using this : CREATE CUSTOM INDEX ON device_by_username ( comm_nr ) USING 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.SASIIndex' WITH OPTIONS = {
'analyzed' : 'true',
'analyzer_class' : 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.analyzer.NonTokenizingAnalyzer',
'case_sensitive' : 'false',
'mode' : 'CONTAINS'
}; which seems to work so far